# Function to remove periods and spaces

Tags: c++

I need to create a function that will remove all periods from a sentence and the spaces

It is only printing out the first word of the sentence not the whole sentence. If I put "hello. my name is" it will only print "hello" but remove the period. I also need to remove the spaces here is my code so far

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<algorithm>
#include<vector>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;
void removePun(char len, string str);
void removeSpaces(char str);
int main()
{
  string sentence;
  char len;
  getline(cin,sentence);
  removePun(len,sentence);
  removeSpaces(len);

  return 0;

}

void removePun(char len, string str)
{

  for (int i = 0, len = str.length(); i < len; i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(str[i]))
        {
            str.erase(i--, 1);
            len = str.size();
        }
    }

   cout << str;
}
void removeSpaces(char *str)
{
  int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i]; i++)
    {
      if (str[i] != ' ')
      {
      str[count++] = str[i];
      }
    }

    str[count] = '\0';

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**The reason** is that `cin` always considers spaces (whitespaces, tabs, new-line...) as terminating the value being input, and thus extracting a string means to always extract a single word, not a phrase or an entire sentence.

To get an entire line from `cin`, there exists a function, called `getline`, that takes the stream (cin) as first argument, and the string variable as second. For example:

```
string removeEvery(string str)
{
  int len = str.size();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        if (ispunct(str[i]))
        {
            str.erase(i--, 1);
            len = str.size();
        }
    }

   return str;
}

int main()
{
  string sentence;
  getline(cin, sentence);
  sentence = removeEvery(sentence);
  cout << sentence;
  return 0;
}
```

Note that `removeEvery` now returns a `string` because as you had it the change is local to that function. If you meant for the cleaned string to be local to `removeEvery` then you can leave it as you had it, just recall the `getline` function. There's a lot more info on input/output handling [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/) in the official reference.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with your period removal code. I think the reason it's not printing the whole sentence is because you are using cin >> which uses whitespace as delimiter and extracts only a part of the whole sentence. You can fix this by using getline.

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

bool compareSongs(std::string a, std::string b)
{
    return a < b;
}

void sortSongsAlphabetically(std::vector<std::string> &songs)
{
    std::sort(songs.begin(), songs.end(), compareSongs); 
}

std::string clean(std::string input)
{
    std::string new_string;
    std::stringstream ss{input};
    std::string word;

    /* parse sentence word by word to remove multiple spaces */
    while(ss >> word) {
       for (char c : word) {
            if (std::isalnum(c) && !std::isspace(c)) {
                new_string += c;
            } 
        }
        new_string += " ";
    }
    return new_string;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> songs;
    std::string input;

    const int max_songs = 5;
    int songs_count = 0;

    while(getline(std::cin, input) && songs_count < max_songs) {
        std::string song = clean(input);
        songs.push_back(song); 
    }

    /* sort songs alphabetically */
    sortSongsAlphabetically(songs);

    std::cout << "Alphabetically sorted songs:" << std::endl;
    for (auto song : songs) {
        std::cout << song << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

You can see it [live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/pAzuXBxwtUgxiNfe)

Comment: what about to remove a space?

Comment: how can i make this to get multiple inputs and it changes each one

Comment: I've updated the code to get multiple inputs and remove spaces as well.

Comment: Much better to make `RemovePun` return the string.  Then you can do other things with it, and it means the function has a single responsibility.  If you make the function remove spaces as well as punctuation, one should change the name.  Perhaps `clean`.

Comment: You are right, I didn't want to change much and tried to keep it close to the OP's code for a better understanding but you are absolutely right, it should be as you suggested.

Comment: is their a tool to removre dashes also like isspace?

Comment: for this problem /I have to create a function to remove spaces, periods, and they want the user to enter a list of songs and alphabetize it im confused on how to first let the user enter a list of songs

Comment: how can I update it to first allow the user to enter say 5 songs then   remove multiple spaces and periods

Comment: @user12230466 check the updated code. You can create a vector of strings to create the list of all songs. The input is first filtered to remove multiple spaces, periods and then stored in the vector. Finally, you can use std::sort to sort the songs list alphbetically.